# Can name from build.sbt depend on Activator name in activator.properties (or vice versa)?

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator

Just noticed that there are two `name` settings in any [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator) template - one in `build.sbt` and another in `activator.properties`.

Is there a way to make one depend on (use the value of) the other? Although the build's `name` can be defaulted to the name of the main project folder, I'm not sure about the activator's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `build.sbt` write out or modify `activator.properties`, using whatever scala code you want to use for that.

But you'd still have to check `activator.properties` in to git because the Activator template-publication system does not run sbt on the project, it just looks at the files in git.

And also your nice template intended for end-users would end up with some extraneous build code in it to generate `activator.properties`, which would clutter up the example.

You could try going the other way but I think it won't work.

In sbt, `name` is a setting rather than a task, and is thus evaluated only once -- so if you made it read from `activator.properties`, you'd need to restart (or at least reload) your sbt build whenever you edited `activator.properties`. But you could read from `activator.properties` using whatever scala code you like. Something like:

```
name := {
  val props = new java.util.Properties()
  props.load(new java.io.FileReader(file("activator.properties")))
  props.getProperty("name")
}
```

However, this is going to fail for two reasons.

When a template is instantiated (cloned) by an end user:

1. activator.properties is dropped
2. activator tries to replace the name in build.sbt with a user-selected one

So on clone, first the above code would fail due to missing `activator.properties`, and second the user's selected name wouldn't be swapped in (because the above expression is too complicated for activator to figure out how to replace it).

This name-replacement means your `build.sbt` name will get dropped in most cases anyway. The one exception is if the user downloads the "template bundle" (a pre-cloned zip of the project) from the template's detail page on typesafe.com, then the name in your `build.sbt` would be kept.

Note that if you ever change the name in `activator.properties` then you'd end up duplicating your template (you'd effectively be publishing a new template), so you may not want to abstract this anyway -- you should change it only when creating a new template is your intent.

Perhaps the bottom line is KISS -- write the name in two places. The alternatives are all going to cause headaches.

The only way I can think of to make this sane would be to have some code *outside* of the template which generated the template. Akka and Play both do this, I think, for templates that are part of the larger akka and play source trees. But at this point you're definitely doing more work than I'd do just to avoid copying one name string around, you'd want to have some other reason to go there.